# On demand modal rendering?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As I currently understand them, jquery modals are rendered during page load and triggered by the user via a hidden= true to hidden=false value.

This is all fine and dandy and works nicely when modals are kept to a minimum per page. But, and here is my question, what if you have an entire list of modals that when you click on it pops up a modal of information to edit. Say for example, a grid of documents and you wish to click on a document and have a modal pop up to just edit the small document. Wouldn't rendering all these documents during page load slow down user experience. Isn't there a way to load and render that modal "on demand".

Whats the standard practice for this type of behavior.

I know the rails way to is load a new page per document but I'm very curious to see how I can make this work.

I tagged the jQuery crowd also as this library is the one I'm most familiar with.

Comment: There is a User Experience (http://ux.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site. That would probably be a better place to ask the "standard practice" question.

Comment: As i'm working under rails and wanting to use the tagged technologies I figured. but i'll ask there also thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this a lot in my apps.  This is the code for a feedback button in one of my apps.

It creates the dialog, and when a button is pressed the dialog's content is loaded dynamically.

```
$(function () {
    var button= $("#FeedbackButton");
    if (button.length == 0)
        button= $("<div id='FeedbackButton'>Feedback</div>").hide().appendTo("body");


    var dialog = $("#FeedbackDialog");
    if (dialog.length == 0)
        dialog = $("<div id='FeedbackDialog'>Feedback</div>").hide().appendTo("body");

    button.click(function () {
        button.hide();
        dialog.load("_FeedbackDialog.htm");
        $(dialog).dialog({
            title: "Feedback",
            modal: true,
            width: 800,
            height: 300,
            close: function () {
                $(button).show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I like this, but question. what would your view code look like in requard to the button.click code, basically how are you tying this itno your view. or what is triggering it.

Comment: Oh, it's just a button click.  I deleted the code where I created the button because it was kind of irrelevant (or so I thought). My script was intended to run once on any page and create all the feedback functionality, including adding the button.  I'll add it back in there.  However, since this loads on code, this will just bind to whatever button you please.  It's in no way specific.

Comment: Ok you're creating the button dynamically, you've showed me its possible and I think i got the gist of it to make it work with multiple buttons/links on the same page. Thanks

Comment: I'll accept the answer in a few see if anyone gives me more options

Comment: LOL, no problem.  Let me know if there is anything I haven't covered.

Answer (score 1):

By rendering a modal on demand, I assume you mean responding to an AJAX query.  In that case, yes there is a way to build a modal on demand.  What you'd have to do is set up an event listener that does an AJAX call to your controller.

```
# my_view.html
/* inside JS event trigger */
$.get("/get_modal.js")
```

Then in your controller, respond to that AJAX call.

```
# my_controller.rb
def get_modal
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js # this will execute get_modal.js (or get_modal.js.erb)
  end
end
```

Your "view", however will not be HTML, it will be JS which leaves you free to do whatever want.

```
# get_modal.js
/* JS modal code */
```

Comment: I'm with you and like this approach also but how would you trigger the $.get("/xxxx") inside a rails .html.erb?

Comment: Treat the .html.erb file the same way you would any .html file and add a `<script>` tag in which you have `$(document).ready` defined.  This then allows you to initialize an event listener on a DOM element.